# Callback error: Specific cast is not valid

Tags: vb.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm using a devexpress editform on my visual basic project. I ask for user input on a `ASPxGridView`, one of the values is called, `Start Date` which is declare on the grid as:

```
<dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="Start Date" FieldName="StartDate" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" UnboundType="String" EditFormSettings-VisibleIndex="1" >
                            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="D" EditFormatString="D" ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired ="true"></PropertiesDateEdit>
                            </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
```

And the datasource looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SpEdPortalConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="ProcedureName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        UpdateCommand="ProcedureName" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        InsertCommand="ProcedureName" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        ***
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
       ***
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        ***
         <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate"   Type="String" />
        ***
    </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Problem: Even if I actually select a datevalue for the StartDate the value inserted on the DB is null.

Note:The callback error only shows on the deployed server not on local environment.But on local it inserts null so seems like the problem is there too but is not throwing an exeption.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the cause but the problem was solve by adding an EditTemplate tag and manually binding the value as follows:

```
                           <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="Start Date" FieldName="StartDate"   HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" UnboundType="String" EditFormSettings-VisibleIndex="1" >
                            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="D" EditFormatString="D" ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired ="true"></PropertiesDateEdit>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dteSD" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="dteSD"
                                            Date='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'>
                                        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
```

If the format changes you can just add `Theme` property inside the `dx:ASPxDateEdit` tag